# Let us view a comment's markdown after 5 minutes even if we can't modify it

Tags: feature-request, comments

I'm suggesting this because it would be a slight quality of life improvement for me. Sometimes, I'll make a comment and want to:

1. Turn it into its own question
2. Post it elsewhere (e.g., in a chat room, in an email, on a forum, etc.).
3. Incorporate it into the original question, as it contains relevant information.

After five minutes has passed, <s>the edit link shows an error pop-over instead of allowing me to *view the markdown* like before</s> the edit link disappears which means I can't see the original markdown.

If I want to reuse the comment elsewhere, I have to copy the plaintext and add markdown back to it manually. It would prefer a way to retain access to the markdown, even if I'm not allowed to modify it.

---

Let me know if this is more appropriate as a separate meta question, but for the same reasons mentioned above, it would be convenient if I could view the markdown of comments I did not write. In addition to the benefits mentioned above:

4. It would make it easier to quote the comment I'm replying to, formatting and all.
5. It would allow me to learn markdown by viewing other comments.

Comment: Given that the [comment's Markdown is available through the SE API](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment), a userscript could be implemented to accomplish what you want. From time to time when I've wanted the Markdown for a comment, I've used the various endpoint pages on [api.stackexchange.com/doc](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/) to get the Markdown. There are also browser extensions which allow you to copy text as Markdown. This isn't intended to indicate an opinion on this feature request, other than that it's faster to get/create a solution than to wait for a feature from SE.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd probably be even more in support of something like this if it was a "copy Markdown with attribution" button that formatted the comment as a quote including all the links/attribution requirements in CC BY-SA.

Comment: If you don't refresh the page your own comment edit link remains indefinitely & lets you get at your own markdown even though you can't save any more. PS Since this isn't site-specific it belongs on [meta.se].

Comment: Regarding learning markdown: it's all in the help link. The options in comments are really limited so there should be no need to learn from existing comments. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting . The most complicated thing you can do is a link.

Comment: @Gimby ah, tbh I never noticed that link until now. Thanks.